# I cannot have ".add(role)" and ".remove(role)" at the same line of code || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, here is my command:

```
const {GuildMember, Embed, InteractionCollector, CommandInteraction} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",

    execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) {
                interaction.reply({ content: "This command does NOT exist any more!", ephemeral: true });
            }
            command.execute(interaction, client);
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const { customId } = interaction;

            if(customId == "verify") {
                const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1060524965427953684"); //Community Role ID
                const role_remove = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1065321229625606215'); //Unverified Role ID
                return interaction.member.roles
                .remove(role_remove)
                .add(role)
                .then((member) => 
                interaction.reply({
                    content: `${role} has been assigned to you!`, 
                    ephemeral: true,
                    })
                )
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    },
};
```

I want it just like that: When someone clicks the Verify Button: 1)First give the Verified Role and 2)Remove the Unverified Role. But when I click the "Verification" Button it sends me an error saying:
`TypeError: interaction.reply(...).add is not a function`.
If there is anyone that can help me, please, reply. Thanks!

Comment: If you are in an async function simply do
``await interaction.member.roles.remove(role_remove);
await interaction.member.roles.add(role);``

Comment: @Oreoezi Unfortunately I'm not in an async function `execute(interaction, client)` and this does not work on my code. I edited my post so you can see the entire code.

Comment: not really experienced with that lib, but if I'm not reading the docs wrong, the methods add/remove returns the member itself (GuildMember instance) inside a Promise. So, you'd need to access the property "roles" again (GuildMemberRoleManager instance). Also, since it's a promise, you'd probably need to do so inside .then(). What I mean is something like `interaction.member.roles.remove(x).then((member) => member.roles.add(y).then((member2) => interaction.reply(...)));` (yeah, not that beautiful). Finally, in your edit, you removed the "add()" (I suppose accidentally).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user19513069, The correct answer (Line of code) is:

```
const {GuildMember, Embed, InteractionCollector, CommandInteraction} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",

    execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) {
                interaction.reply({ content: "This command does NOT exist any more!", ephemeral: true });
            }
            command.execute(interaction, client);
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const { customId } = interaction;

            if(customId == "verify") {
                const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1060524965427953684"); //Community Role ID
                const role_remove = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1065321229625606215'); //Unverified Role ID
                **interaction.member.roles
                .remove(role_remove)
                .then((member) => 
                member.roles
                .add(role)
                .then((member2) => 
                interaction.reply({
                    content: `${role} has been assigned to you!`, 
                    ephemeral: true,
                })));**
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    },
};
```